# Migration of old project from C++Builder 10.2 to 10.2.3 crashes at runtime

Tags: clang, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a very hard time upgrading our old C++Builder 10.2 project to 10.2.3 (we are using the Clang compiler, 32bit application on a 64bit PC).

The 10.2.3 installation went OK (on a clean Windows 10 PC), - the project compiles and links - everyone is happy so far.

But, when running the application in the debugger, I can see that the `this` pointer for the MainForm (a rather large object, for historic reasons) suddenly changes to garbage across a single method invocation call (when calling one of its own methods - just after the constructor is finished) which leads to a crucial failure.

I have tried to comment out the `__fastcall` calling convention for the particular method, and then the debugger goes a bit further, but then crashes in the next method invocation using `__fastcall` due to `this` pointer corruption (we have 1000+ methods with `__fastcall`, so commenting them all out is not an option).

Does anyone have a clue what is happening?

A new Clang compiler switch, maybe?

Issue with large objects?

I also tried to build a brand new project from scratch in 10.2.3 - but with no luck - the same weird thing happens.

Comment: without code or any description related to the techniques used it is impossible to mimic the behavior or debug. If you created new app from scratch and that crashes may be you should share its code. Also are you sure the old compiled App is working on new windows installation (had problems in the past that actually newer windows update/version caused the problem instead of new compiler)?

Comment: In 32bit `__fastcall`, the `this` pointer is carried in the `EAX` cpu register.  Use the debugger to find out exactly what is trashing that register during each `__fastcall` method invocation. Sounds like maybe the clang compiler is not setting up the call stacks correctly. Are you using C++11 in your code? If not, try switching back to the legacy Borland compiler and see if the same problem happens (it shouldn't).

Comment: Hi Remy - thanks for your answer. Switching back to the classic compiler is not possible for us any longer since we heavy make use of modern C++ (the main reason for switching to Clang anyway). I will try to debug and follow the EAX CPU register closely

Comment: @Spektre : yes our rather old code base runs fine without any problems when compiling under 10.2. We had some hard time with the debugger that is why we are now trying to upgrading to 10.2.3. the 'this' pointer issue is seen on both Windows 7 and 10 PC's

Comment: :0084556F TfrmMacTalk::search_dlllanguagefiles(this=:00845239)
:007E6A74 TfrmMacTalk::mt_load_language(this=:075F3720)
:007E30E0 TfrmMacTalk::Init2(this=:075F3720, FileToOpen=:0019FE4C)
:0040E9C0 wWinMain(hInstance=:00400000, hPrevInstance=NULL, lpCmdLine=:04DF2AE8, nCmdShow=9)
:0136b8cb ; __wstartup
:77e94a77 ; ntdll.dll
:77e94a47 ; ntdll.dll

Comment: the tiny stack dump reveal clearly that the 'this' pointer changes from 0x075F3720 to 0x00845239 when method 'mt_load_language' invokes 'search_dlllanguagefiles' ditto without any arguments (sorry for the stack dump formatting)

Comment: Well after some debugging I can see that the failure happens after the call to $01356e90  : (which is _chkstk). In 10.2 the 'this' pointer is restored correctly after not in 10.2.3 :
All happens very early when the compiler is setting up the stack frame

00845593 B894480000       mov eax,$00004894         // well save 'this'?? 
00845598 E8F318B100       call $01356e90            // call _chkstk
0084559D 8B842494480000   mov eax,[esp+$4894]       // restore this pointer (works in 10.2 not in 10.2.3)

Comment: Button line conclusion is : '_chkstk' crashes the stack frame in 10.2.3 Solution : Avoid putting 'large' objects/arrays on the stack - instead consider using the heap store instead  i.e. new, std::shared_ptr<>, std::unique_ptr<>, ... etc.

Comment: Spent 3 days to debug random AV and made the same conclusion. A large __fastcall functions call corrupts the callstack just after "call esp". If I make the function smaller, it works. I am now in the process of getting rid of all possible __fastcalls (old code)

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in the Clang compilers, which has already been reported to Embarcadero:

[RSP-12769: bcc32c have problems with __fastcall calling convention](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12769)

[RSP-20171: Tokyo 10.2.3 clang destroys this pointer if stack is large](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20171)

[RSP-20173: BCC32C parameter corruption with more than 4KB of data on a stack frame](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20173)

A patch for the Clang compilers in 10.2.3 Tokyo is available on Embarcadero's CodeCentral:

[ID: 30834, C++Builder 10.2.3 C++ Compiler 4k Stack Allocation Patch](https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30834)

Comment: ahh OK, - if you know what to look for then there might be an answer/a conclusion for your problem(s) :-). Thanks for information